# Trouble carrying out symbolic operations on matrixes

Tags: matrix, symbolic

I have some problems.

First of all, I declare matrices like below

```
$Assumptions = {
  Element[X, Matrices[{m, n}]], 
  Element[T, Matrices[{n, k}]], 
  Element[Y, Matrices[{m, k}]]};
```

and I want to apply

```
transpose(X T - Y).(X T - Y) = 
  transpose[T].transpose[X].X.T - transpose[T].transpose[X].Y - 
  transpose[Y].X.T + transpose[Y].Y
```

so I tried

1. `Inner[Times, {X \[Transpose]}, {T \[Transpose]}, Plus] - \[Transpose][Y]`
2. `Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, {X}, {T}] - {Y} = {-Y + X ** T} ...`

But I can not multiply the two above expressions.

```
Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, 
  Inner[Times, {X\[Transpose]}, {T\[Transpose]}, Plus] - Transpose[Y], 
  Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, {X}, {T}] - {Y}]
```

because I get errors. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly well for me. The only thing I see that is wrong is that you forgot the braces for `Transpose[Y]`, so the code should look like this:

```
Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, 
Inner[Times, {X\[Transpose]}, {T\[Transpose]}, Plus] - {Transpose[Y]}, 
Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, {X}, {T}] - {Y}]
```