# How can I get Mathematica to recognize equality of symbolic matrix expressions?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic, tensors

I have two matrix expressions:

```
X.Transpose[T].Transpose[X]
```

and

```
X.T.Transpose[X]
```

I want *Mathematica*  to recognize that these expressions are equal. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Answer probably depends on how you plan to use this known relation. Can you clarify the use case?

Comment: I am confused. Why are these equal?  `x = RandomReal[1, {4, 4}]; t = RandomReal[1, {4, 4}]; z0 = x.Transpose[t].Transpose[x]; z1 = x.t.Transpose[x];
z1 - z0` gives ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VG7KO.png) should this not be all zeros if they are equal?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31184/89)?

Comment: @Nasser I don't think that the OP means they are equal in general, but more in a `$Assumptions` kind of way.

Comment: @Nasser Huh, but that's how `$Assumptions` are usually used for, no? The only question is if it will be helpful for the OP, as kirma pointed out...

Comment: @sebhofer I only used assumptions to tell M to use Element[] and assume certain values, as in `x>0` and such. Never used it to tell it that one expression is the same as another. But again, good to know one can do this.

Comment: Could you be so kind to explain what you expected? One user has some doubts as you can see under my answer, now you should make the statement clear enough.

Answer (score 7):

We can easily verify the assumption that your matrices are equal is wrong, e.g. let's take two `2 x 2` matrices:

```
A = {{10, 5}, {2, 2}};
B = {{1, 0}, {1, 6}};
```

now we have

```
A.B.Transpose[A] == A.Transpose[B].Transpose[A]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

However a simple fact in linear algebra says that the former matrix is equal to the latter one transposed.

```
TraditionalForm[ X.T.Transpose[X] == Transpose[X.Transpose[T].Transpose[X]] ]
```

[image]

Now we can exploit new tensor capabilities in *Mathematica 9*, first 
assume that `X` and `T` are `n x m` matrices:

```
$Assumptions = (X | T) ∈  Matrices[{n, m}];
```

then we can use e.g. `TensorReduce`:

```
TensorReduce[ X.T.Transpose[X] == Transpose[ X.Transpose[T].Transpose[X]] ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: @sebhofer Most of this site users know well this simple identity in linear algebra. I demonstrated that his "theorem" is not true by providing a simple example. Then I showed what kind of identity he could assumed and next solved that problem. My answer is clear enough even for  first-year student.

Comment: With considerable effort, I could interpret OP asking how to provide assumption that `T` is symmetric. If this is the case, formulation of the question is not very direct.

Comment: I was wrong, sorry... I thought one could construct an example where `T-Transpose@T` is in the null-space of `X`, but this is not possible. I should have thought further first. Sorry for the fuzz!

Comment: @kirma If you want such an assumption use `$Assumptions = 
 G ∈  Matrices[{n, n}, Complexes, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]`. Then `TensorReduce[G - Transpose[G]]` yields `0`. If your interpretation would be the case one should have assumed `Det[X] != 0` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly your expressions are the same only when the matrix `T` is symmetric. With this assumption, Mathematica can prove your expressions are equal using:

```
TensorReduce[
    X.Transpose[T].Transpose[X] == X.T.Transpose[X],
    Assumptions -> X ∈ Matrices[{n, n}] && T ∈ Matrices[{n,n}, Symmetric[{1,2}]]
]
```

> True