# Symbolic linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic, tensors

I would like to know how I can ask *Mathematica* to expand (and simplify) such an expression :

$$ (\alpha A + \beta B)^\top (\alpha A + \beta B) $$

where $\alpha,\beta$ are two real numbers and $A,B$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. $A^\top$ denotes the transpose of $A$. I assume I must tell *Mathematica* that $A$ and $B$ are vectors. Here is what I have tried :

```
$Assumptions = (A | B) [Element] Vectors[n];
    $Assumptions = (a | b) [Element] Reals;
TensorExpand[ Transpose[a*A + b*B].(a*A + b*B) ]
```

and the output is :

```
a A.Transpose[a A + b B, {2, 1}] + b B.Transpose[a A + b B, {2, 1}]
```

Which is not what I expected since I would like the output to be :

$$ \alpha^{2} A^\top A + 2 \alpha \beta A^\top B + \beta^{2} B^\top B $$

Comment: You can do no harm by trying.

Comment: I would if I had Mathematica on the computer I'm currently using but I don't. I can't try it right now but I will later.

Comment: This is closely related: [How can I get Mathematica to recognize equality of symbolic matrix expressions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31188/how-can-i-get-mathematica-to-recognize-equality-of-symbolic-matrix-expressions). In fact, following the answer you should resolve your prolem, i.e. use `TensorReduce` instead of `FullSimplify`.

Comment: I have tried :

    $Assumptions = (A | B) \[Element] Matrices[{n, 1}];
    TensorExpand[ Transpose[A + B].(A + B) ]

But the output I get is not 

    Transpose[A].A + 2Transpose[A].B + Transpose[B].B

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: You can use `Vectors[n]`. In your original question you have `( a*A + b*B)]*( a*A + b*B)`, instead of `*` use `.` i.e. `Dot` or you can use `TensorProduct`.

Comment: $Assumptions = (A | B) \[Element] Vectors[n];
TensorExpand[ Transpose[a*A + b*B].(a*A + b*B) ]
gives : a A.Transpose[a A + b B, {2, 1}] + b B.Transpose[a A + b B, {2, 1}].

Comment: Neither assumptions on `a` nor `b`?

Comment: I added $Assumptions = (a | b) \[Element] Reals; However, the output remains the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you're working with vectors, just let Mathematica know that these are vectors.  Some other systems (MATLAB and its relatives in particular) have the limitation that they can *only* work with matrices, forcing you to distinguish between row vector and column vectors and keep transposing.  This is not necessary nor convenient in Mathematica.

```
In[1]:= $Assumptions = a ∈ Vectors[n, Reals] && b ∈ Vectors[n, Reals]
Out[1]= a ∈ Vectors[n, Reals] && b ∈ Vectors[n, Reals]

In[2]:= (α a + β b).(α a + β b) // TensorExpand
Out[2]= α^2 a.a + 2 α β a.b + β^2 b.b
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to work just fine in your example. However, would it still work if I had `Transpose[]` to your example ?

Comment: @jibounet Well, does it make any sense to transpose a vector?

Comment: I think it does. A real vector $X$ belongs to $\mathrm{Mat}_{n,1}(\mathbb{R})$. We can define its transpose to be the matrix of the linear form $L_{X} \, : \, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \, \longmapsto \, \left\langle X,Y \right\rangle$, which is an element of $\mathrm{Mat}_{1,n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @jibounet For Mathematica a "vector" is a 1-dimensional tensor.  What people call a "row vector" is a really a matrix, i.e. a 2-dimensional tensor.  It's more difficult to reason about those and figure out such things that $AB^T=BA^T$ *only* if both A and B are 1 by $n$ matrices, but not otherwise.  In Mathematica *it does not make sense to transpose a vector because it's a one-dimensional structure*.

Comment: Alright. I understand.